# Get an equation from user and use it as offset for drawing data values - Charts are being drawn using highcharts

Tags: javascript, parsing, highcharts

I am adding a functionality to my project.

Currently, I get data from database and draw charts using highcharts.

Now I want the user to input an equation lets say: y = x^2  --> so user enters x^2 in a textbox field.

Now the graph should be drawn by squaring each value that is fetched from the database.

My main concern is how to parse the text and get the equation. Javascript solution is preferable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from input by:

```
$('#idinput').val();
```

and then parse by parseFloat() function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp Then run ajax and get data from database.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my question.

What I mean is: The user enters a formula as a string and I need to parse it and then substitute the value from database in place of the variable.

Comment: Anyway, what user enter in input, i.e "12" or "Value is 12" or something different?